# Is HashSet implementation in Java a good example for Adapter Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

I have recently looked into the source code of HashSet Collection class
and found out that It is backed by HashMap. HashSet is delegating all its method calls to HashMap. So I'm just wondering if this is a good example for adapter pattern .

Comment: Why would you think it is? Delegation is only part of adapter. Where's the API you need to use but can't change? Assuming you mean object adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's not an adapter.

Adapters wrap other objects to change their method signatures to match some other interface.  That's not really the case here.  `HashSet` isn't turning a `Map` into a Set.  It just uses a set internally to do its work.

If you made a class that had a `String` field, would say you are adapting the string? No, you are just using it.

Comment: Delegating the method calls to HashMap made me think that It is using Adapter pattern. All the methods are delegating their work to HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because functionality is acutally being lost. A `java.util.Set` only stores keys whereas a `java.util.Map` stores keys and values. They are not equivelant.

An adapter is typically something which adapts one interface to another where both interfaces do the same / similar thing, but have different signatures. An adapter could be made to adapt a `java.util.Enumeration` to a `java.util.Iterator` for example. Or perhaps an adapter between `java.io.InputStream` and `java.io.Writer` such as the `java.io.InputStreamWriter`.